# Counting Facebook Graph API requests

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I request a user's tagged places using the Facebook Graph API and receive back 200 places (in groups of 25, more or less) does that count as one API request or 200?

I know if I ask for 5 specific Ids it'll be counted as 5 separate API calls but I'm wondering about when you are asking for everything. You won't know how much data is coming back. If it counts as one API call then great, but if it's 200 then I'll need some mechanism to gather the data over a longer period of time.

This is the API call.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/tagged_places

Comment: please add the exact api call in question

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/tagged_places      https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting The API limiting suggests each piece of info received counts as an API call, even ifyou only make one call.

Comment: so what IS the api call in question? you always need to add as much information as possible to your stackoverflow questions.

Comment: also, please do not add important information in comments, always edit your question

Answer (score 0):

One call to the API is...well, one API call, obviously. If you call the API one time and get 25 items in the result, it will be one API call. You can increase the limit and it will still be one API call.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting#what-do-we-consider-an-api-call-

The example in the docs shows that one request can also count as several API calls, if you ask for some specific IDs.

If you get 200 results, you either increased the limit or you used paging. Since you mentioned "in groups of 25", i assume you are using paging. Which means, you would need 8 API calls to get 200 items.